# Android: Memory leak causing OOM when using setImageURI

Tags: java, android, imageview, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

i've only programmed java a couple of days so be gentle... :P

My app uses a SQLite database to save different "projects" that needs user provided text, photo and location. The problem is that when browsing through some of the project a Out of Memory-exception occurs when loading the

> myImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(msavePicture));

for the fourth of fifth time. When using DDMS you can see that the allocated memory increases about 0.2Mbyte every new load. I've searched the problem and tried using

> myImage.setImageDrawable(null);

but the issue remains. I've also tried changing the code to

> ```
>   myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(msavePicture);
>   ImageView myImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
>   myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
> ```

so i could use .recycle(); but the picture doesent load, it returns null.
msavePicture is a string that looks like this:

> file:///mnt/sdcard/MyCameraApp/IMG_2011-12-09-01-49.jpg

i've included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in manifest and i know the picture exists because when using setImageURI it works.

So the question is: What am i doing wrong to cause the memory leak, how to truly destroy the ImageView, or why can't Bitmapfactory decode my string, is the file location wrong?

I've included alot of the activity just in case.  Any solution or links regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

(PS: If someone knows a guide how to save a SQLite database to a server so you can update other phones with it would also be greatly appreciated! =)   :DS)

```
  public class Page3 extends Activity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
public static Long Row = (long) 40;
public static String summarydec = "FAIL";
public static String msavePicture;
public static Location loc;
private EditText mgps_lati;
private EditText mgps_long;
static String gps_long;
static String gps_lati;
private TodoDbAdapter mDbHelper;
public Location myLocation;
public static Bitmap myBitmap;
public Uri uBitmap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    mDbHelper = new TodoDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);


        if(msavePicture == null){
        msavePicture = "";
    }
 //     myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(msavePicture);
 //     ImageView myImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
 //     myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);       

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    myImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(msavePicture));

    mgps_long = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gps_long); 
    mgps_lati = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gps_lati);
    mgps_lati.setText("Latitude:  "+gps_lati);
    mgps_long.setText("Longitude: "+gps_long);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///// G P S  -  L Y S S N A R E ////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

    Button gps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gps);
    gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (gps_lati != null && gps_long != null) {
                mgps_lati.setText("Latitude:  " +gps_lati);
                mgps_long.setText("Longitude: " +gps_long);
                TodoDetails.save_gps_long = gps_long;
                TodoDetails.save_gps_lati = gps_lati;
                Page1.save_gps_long = gps_long;
                Page1.save_gps_lati= gps_lati;
                Page2.save_gps_long = gps_long;
                Page2.save_gps_lati= gps_lati;
                } else {
                    String Latitude = "Fel vid GPS-hanteringen, arra det!";
                    String Longitude = "Fel vid GPS-hanteringen, arra det!";
                    mgps_lati.setText(Latitude);
                    mgps_long.setText(Longitude);
                }
        }});
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Button camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {                
            createCamera();
        }});

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_button);
    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {                
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            TodoDetails.mPIC = msavePicture;
            Page1.mPIC = msavePicture;
            Page2.mPIC = msavePicture;
            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            myImage.setImageDrawable(null);
 //             myBitmap.recycle();
            cancelTimer();
            finish();
        }

    });
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    cancelTimer();
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    myImage.setImageDrawable(null);

}
protected void cancelTimer()
{
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    myLocation.cancelTimer();   
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    cancelTimer();  
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    myImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(msavePicture));

 //     ImageView myImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
 //     myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(msavePicture);
 //     myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
public void onBackPressed (){
    cancelTimer();  
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    myImage.setImageDrawable(null);
 //     Bitmap myBitmap = Page3.myBitmap;
//      myBitmap.recycle();
    finish();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////// A L L A   V Y E R ///////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private void createPage1() {
    Intent b = new Intent(this, Page1.class);
    startActivityForResult(b, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, b);
    finish();
}
private void createPage2() {
    Intent b = new Intent(this, Page2.class);
    startActivityForResult(b, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, b);
}
private void createTodo() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TodoDetails.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
}
private void createCamera() {
    Intent c = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
    startActivityForResult(c, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, c);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////// M E N U  T O O L B A R //////////////////////////
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.projektlist, menu);
    return true;
}
public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(final Location location){
        gps_lati = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        gps_long = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        }};
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should downscale the bitmap to the size of your ImageView. For example:

```
int ratio = widhtOriginal / widthImageView;
// Just an example, you should use more sophisticated algorithm

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = ratio;

InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
// Will work for Uri's with "content" scheme,
// otherwise use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String, Options) and so on

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties realizing your example-code. Can't get the inputstream working, tried Uri.parse(msavePicture) that would open the file located at the given source, right? BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null as previously mentioned. 
Do you really need to resize a picture to fit a view? Sounds overly complicated. Thank you for trying, if i misunderstood anything please let me know..!

Comment: That's really necessary to avoid OOM - I ran into the same problem and downscaling helped. When opening InputStream you need to distinguish the schemes defined in the Uri. See [how it's implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.resolveUri()) in ImageView and adapt it for your app.